# Validation in mvc4 not taking place

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

MODEL

```
public class SearchTerm
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage="please enter")]
   public string SearchTrm { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    ....
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SearchTrm)</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SearchTrm)

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Home")) 
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("SelectedFieldId", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID", "NiceName", Model.SelectedFieldId));
    }
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchTerm Model)
{
    // some code here....
}
```

When i click a empty search I want the validation message to take place but instead page is getting postback and i am having `NullReferenceException`

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid.

Comment: ok i removed the  second forms but still it doesnt work

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: page is still getting postback on an empty search .i want the validation message to be displayed

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts for client side validation?

Comment: u just answered my question thanks mate silly mistake

Comment: wait sorry its still not working i added this  
script for validation under @section{}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Comment: i believe that you've added your `model` in the beginning of your view file.

Comment: Is `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` included before `/bundles/jqueryval`? (or included in the layout)?

Comment: /bundles/jquery is in layout

and /bundles/jqueryval in the search view

Comment: can you show us your script part in `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: <head>
  
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
     </body>

Comment: can you try with, clean  new application?

Answer (score 0):

Mention the script name, @section scripts { ...} and check whether jqueryval has 2 files - ~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js","~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js","~/scripts